# Starting Amulator (AVD) for mobile and not for wear Arm

Tags: android

Friends i am new in android Platform. I wanted to created Mobiles apps and not Wear Arm's Apps . i have installed **4.4w(API 20 packages** and start Emulator after selecting Screen Attributes. But it **showing display only for Wear ARM And Not For Mobiles** 
which Package version I have to install (4.4.2,4.4.3 ..... ) 
I will be very thankful to you !

Answer (score 0):

4.4W is for [Android Wear](http://developer.android.com/wear/index.html) especially, I mean it's Wear SDK. You can download/install any of the other SDKs available like 4.4, 4.3, 4.2 or any.

Answer (score 0):

4.4 **W** is Android **Wear**. You should install API 19 (Android 4.4 Kitkat) and create a new AVD with one of the built-in device definitions, e.g. Nexus 5.